# How to initiate designing a iPaas Product from scratch?

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns, layout, user-centered-design, design-system

As a Product designer working in an iPaas company, I have worked on various features of the product. On both the scenarios like designing a new feature and also improving the existing features. The company purchased a bootstrapped theme before I was hired and hence we had to follow the components of the bootstap theme only, interms of designing the UI. The UX was taken care of me.

Recently the company proposed to develop the product by using the latest tech in the market, using Nex JS, react JS and stuffs.

So what should be my foremost approach to initiate the design of the UI components? Like do we need to make the design system at the earliest or is there any other way to start the design of the product.

The main scope is to at least make and finalize the basic structural layout, and then I will be proceeding with the other stuffs of the UI (means I will start the redesign of the features, after the basic layout is finalized)

Comment: I mean changing the tech doesn't change the product a lot, right? I wouldn't start working from scratch, you probably have user journeys and user flows that could help you out while redesigning the product. I'd start off by shaping the new features of the product that might have impact on current user flows and user journeys, when you finish with that it'll be clearer on how to redesign Bootstrap components (not sure if your company has decided to stay with Bootstrap design system or no).